# Any guidelines to create a polling app on android?

Tags: android

I intend to develop an app on android that can help people selecting the best pizza/ice cream/hot dog in a certain town based on their ratings through a poll.

Now what resources do I need to achieve the desired solution? Do I need a web service or website/device connectivity for the desired poll? I would like to start off with a simple application that just shows polls or ratings for a certain item.

Can somebody shed some light on this idea?

Answer (score 3):

Check this article: [Rapid cloud development using App Engine for the Cycle Hire Widget Android application](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2010/08/rapid-cloud-development-using-app.html)

I've been using [GAE](http://code.google.com/appengine/) a lot lately. It's pretty simple for your application.

- Create the the model of your poll
- Create a servlet in GAE.
- Use [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to convert your info to json.
- Parse it in android with Gson as well.

Comment: I have never worked in GAE. But i'm quite keen to work in it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is just some thoughts out of the blue... but I think the following:

1. Set up a web application (register, sign in, add new stuff, rate present stuff, comments) in some sort of a community. Get it working!
2. Use a local database (sqlite) on your Android app
3. Synchronize the web-based database with the local android database upon request. Don't download the entire database to every application (but you can have that as an option in the settings menu).
4. If you are up for it, use Facebook Connect to allow users to sign in with their facebook account, instead of using the username/password analogy. Smooth and simple for users. Ref: [facebook-android-sdk](http://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/)
5. Use Google API to access google maps and do a location based service like Gowalla and Foursquare.

Personally, I think you have a great idéa. Looking forward to download the application from Android Market in the near future :-)

Comment: Why do you emphasize upon using facebook connect? Wouldn't i be able to make such an app without it. 

Thank you.

Comment: Most definately true Maxmood, you don't have to use Facebook Connect at all. It's just a suggestion to make it easier for your users. Also, with facebook connect, you can allow users to post to their wall creating a buzz around your app. This creates an interest which makes your app more popular and it'll get you more downloads...

Comment: I appreciate we can use FB as a Social Media tool. Now for Gowalla and Foursquare...wonder if you have used them yourself? If yes then how was your experience? Can you refer a tutorial on either of them?

Is it hard and fast for me to use Gowalla or Foursquare?

Comment: @Maxood: Would a google based login not be better for Android? You can't really use Android without at least a dormant GMail account while on the other hand some users might like to stay away from Facebook for privacy reasons.